# How to check system uptime in windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

In windows 7 How to get the system uptime ?

How to know since how long machine is running ?

In earlier versions of windows (XP) it can be easily seen on "Local Area Connection status" by just clicking on Network icon in system tray/taskbar.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User. (http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can been seen in the task manager

1. Right-click on the Taskbar, and click Task Manager. You can also click CTRL+SHIFT+ESC to get to the Task Manager.
2. In Task Manager, select the Performance tab.
3. The current system uptime is shown under System.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Start task manager > performance, there is a system box that shows uptime